# Can I share my vhost to my local workgroup?

Tags: web-server, virtualhost, workgroup

**Scenario:**

- 10 Windows XP computers
- one Airties 206 ADSL modem
- workgroup network
- computer **A** runs Apache web server
- in computer **A** set some virtual host name for some folder in apache

**Question :**

May I do some things for this network and all computer when they enter the virtual host name at the browser the request go directly to Computer **A** instead of going through the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modify the `hosts` file on each machine in the workgroup, I don't see why not.

Or setup a 'local' DNS server that would direct requests internally without ever hitting "the cloud".

Comment: may i set my modem to redirect some url to exact ip ?

Comment: @AmirModiri - I am not familiar with the Airties modem - does it have a built-in DNS resolution feature? Does it handle routing natively, or is there a router on your network? If there is a router, then does it handle DNS resolution>